# problem getting data in mongodb, get by category id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to filter my pets by category, I have the following model of pets:

```js
const Pet = mongoose.model(
    'Pet',
    new Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        age: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
        },
        weight: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
        },
        color: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        images: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
        },
        available: {
            type: Boolean,
        },
        category: Object,
        user: Object,
        adopter: Object,
    }, { timestamps: true }),
);

module.exports = Pet;
```

when I try to get the data through postman it returns an empty array as a response.

my code to filter by category:

```js
static async getByCategory(req, res) {

        const id = req.params.id;

        // check if id is valid
        if (!ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
            res.status(422).json({ msg: 'Invalid ID' });
            return;
        }

        const pets = await Pet.find({ 'category._id': id }).sort('-createdAt');

        if (!pets) {
            res.status(404).json({ msg: 'Pets not found!' });
            return;
        }

        res.status(200).json({ pets });
    }
```

it's my first time using mongodb so i'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check that your MongoDB indeed has a field `category._id`?

Comment: yes it does, in document pets the object category is being filled with the correct data with the _id of the category and the name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It appears this is a comment and not an answer to the question. Once you have enough reputation you will be allowed to comment directly on questions. For further information, please see [how to give good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

`id` being passed from the client side is string and the one which is saved in the db is `ObjectId`. Convert the string to Mongoose ObjectId before `Pet.find()`.

```
const id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);

const pets = await Pet.find({ 'category._id': id }).sort('-createdAt');
```

> Don't forget to import 'mongoose'.